# Hibernate annotations many to many inverse relationship with eager fetch

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

> Hi there,
>
> > i have a model of user and role with many to many relationship as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@Indexed
@XmlRootElement
public class User extends BaseObject implements Serializable, UserDetails,     PersistentObject, HasRevision, org.activiti.engine.identity.User {

private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name = "USER_ROLE",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") },
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")
)
public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}
public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
} 
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLE")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
            name = "findRoleByName",
            query = "select r from Role r where r.name = :name "
    )
})
public class Role extends BaseObject implements Serializable, GrantedAuthority {

private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "roles")
public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}
    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}
}
```

> when i create or update the user with assignment of role the exception will come like follows
>
> > user's id: user
> >     org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class [com.model.User] with identifier [user]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.model.User#user]
> >     ....
> >
> > Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.model.User#user]
>
> i cant put lazy instead of eager fetch it will cause some other problem(somewhere i cant get roles from session), and i cant remove inverse relationship it will cause in role deletion.
>
> so how i solve the problem suggestions are welcome and thank in advance.

Comment: The problem is caused by the optimistic locking. You have an @Version attribute in your User entity, and pass an incorrect value. Show us the code causing this exception.

Comment: @JB Nizet thank you yes the version is problem.If i delete version it's work correctly whats wrong in that? i didn't pass any value for version just use version annotation. temporarily i delete the version but whats exact solution. thank you

Comment: Without the code and the complete stack trace of the exception, it's hard to say.

Comment: @JB Nizet thank you, i just see your reply a very late and sorry for that. I changed the old code and remove the version field. Now its working, if i got this exception in future sure i give u more details thank you very much for your response.